# Set item for ComboBox of QT in function

Tags: qt

I want to set item for comboBox of QT in function.
I coded below:

Function:

```
void addItemInComboBoxBaudRate(){
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("2400");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("4800");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("9600");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("19200");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("38400");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("57600");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("115200");
    Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->setCurrentText("9600)");
}
```

In main function:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);   
    addItemInComboBoxBaudRate();
}
```

Error:

/home/san/workspace/build-dieu_khien_san-Desktop-Debug/ui_mainwindow.h:44: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Ui_MainWindow::cbBaudRate'
     QComboBox *cbBaudRate;

/home/san/workspace/dieu_khien_san/mainwindow.cpp:20: error: from this location
     Ui::MainWindow::cbBaudRate->addItem("2400");

Comment: I fixed it! I use variable QComboBox* cbCombo; And main function: cbCombo = ui->cbBaudRate. In function addItemInComboBoxBaudRate use cbCombo instead Ui::MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

change the code into

```
void addItemInComboBoxBaudRate(){
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("2400");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("4800");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("9600");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("19200");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("38400");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("57600");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->addItem("115200");
    Ui::MainWindow->cbBaudRate->setCurrentText("9600)");
}
```

edited: try that way (without the mainwindow.h code I'm just guessing), if it doesn't work, please edit your question with full header file (or a least all the MainWindow class)

Comment: /home/san/workspace/dieu_khien_san/mainwindow.cpp:20: error: 'ui' was not declared in this scope
     ui->cbBaudRate->addItem("2400");